# how to get data on jlist created through design view on jframe in netbeans?

Tags: mysql, swing, netbeans, jlist

I am using Netbeans IDE for my project, I have created a `jframe` class, and from the design view I put a `panel`, on which I have put a `jlist`.

I want to get the names of the databases from MySQL dynamically on to this `jlist`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `JList` is available as a variable inside your form class - just use, e.g.
`jList1.getModel()`....
and do what you want.

But there are database-viewing components for Swing, which will probably be easier than rolling your own database code (remember to close your `PreparedStatements` and `ResultSets` if you do).